# C# Will code execution continue after await?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library, extension-methods

After a lot of readings about await/async, I still have some misunderstanding about the subject.
Please provide a short answer (yes/no) and a long answer to my questions, so I can have better understanding.

Let's say we have the following method:

```
public async Task UnresultTaskMethod()
{
   await AsyncMethod1();
   await AsyncMethod2();
}
```

Questions:

1. When the execution of the code will reach **AsyncMethod1**, will it automatically move to call AsyncMethod2 while AsyncMethod1() is getting executed?
2. When the execution of the code will reach **AsyncMethod2**, will the execution of the method ends, and the execution will return to the caller, before the execution of **AsyncMethod2** completely ends?
3. Is there such a cases where the execution of the method will end before the calls to async method fully completes (for example the method was void instead of task)?
4. When I will need to put `Task.WaitAll(tasks); Task.WhenAll(tasks);` at the end so I can make sure the execution will not continue before all the tasks have ended, this is the main factor of confusion for me, why to wait for a task in this way if you can wait for them by keyword await?
5. I was thinking when the execution will hit async method with await, it will put it on processing schedule, and continue to execute the code inside the function, I'm feeling that I misunderstood.

Comment: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) -- [Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) -- [Async Programming,  Brownfield Async Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development) -- [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

await roughly means 'wait until completed'

1. No
2. No
3. If you don't await, it might be the case, for example

```
public async Task UnresultTaskMethod()
{
   Task.Delay(2000);

   // We haven't awaited, so we're here right away
   await AsyncMethod2();
}
```

4. `Task.WaitAll` and `Task.WhenAll` don't make sense when you await individual tasks right away. However, you can do this:

```
public async Task UnresultTaskMethod()
{ 
   var task1 = AsyncMethod1();
   var task2 = AsyncMethod2();

   // The tasks are now doing their job

   await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
 
   // Here you are sure both task1 and task2 are completed
}
```

With `Task.WaitAll` it would be like this:

```
public async Task UnresultTaskMethod()
{ 
   var task1 = AsyncMethod1();
   var task2 = AsyncMethod2();

   // This is not awaitable, you're blocking the current thread
   Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
 
   // Here you are sure both task1 and task2 are completed
}
```

In this case, you don't need `async Task`, because you are not awaiting, i.e. it is effectively a `void` method.

5. Hopefully now it is a bit clearer